# Unstable router connection

Tags: wireless-access-point

I have a D-link router set up  about 3 meters from my laptop. There are periods when I get disconnected like 6 times a minute. If I set up WEP encryption it gets even worse and speed is so slow I can barely access `http://192.168.0.1/` in order to disable WEP.

The disconnections seem to stop when I change the *channel* setting. Sometimes selecting channel 6 helps. But after a while, the same things happen with channel 6 so I select another channel, like 12 and so on.

Is there anything I can do to make the disconnections stop permanently?

Comment: What router & firmware do you use? How many other WLANs are in range of your router? Do you encounter these problems only at specific times let's say only in the afternoon?

Comment: its "DI-524". if by WLANS u mean other wireless networks, there are like 6 besides mine. Disconnections started a few minutes ago, but I changed channel and they stopped for now..

Comment: please edit your title to match your problem

Comment: What wireless protocol are you attempting to use? Wireless-N (802.11N)? I've had a lot of problems with -N and it's router & computer specific. Some computers will work fine, while others won't with a particular router, whereas the same computer will work fine using a different wireless-N router.

Comment: Six other WIFIs in range is a lot. I guess their WIFI signals are disturbing your own signal. Does your router have a channel overview like [this](http://imgur.com/ZrdkY)? It shows you which channel the other WIFI signals use. If they have *autochannel* active, their channel will (unfortunally) change from time to time.

Comment: my router settings page doesn't have things like that. and it looks like it was made it frontpage.

Comment: when I move mouse over my wirless network, it appears "802.11g", so i guess its not N

Comment: I'd suggest a firmware update but the dlink site shows that the latest firmware version is from 2004 (wow).  That router has mediocre reviews as it is, and a lot list intermittent connectivity issues.  I'd suggest you just go ahead and invest in a newer N router.  No amount of troubleshooting will make up for a bad product.  This isn't an answer to your question really, but it's the best advice I can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DI-524` was introduced about seven years ago as a low-end, low-cost router. You can get mid-range, dual-band routers for around $50 now. It's definitely time to upgrade.